# Animation are displayed at the wrong time while rendering

Tags: rendering, animation, timeline

Hy All

Im working on a quite large video project with blender 2.78.a on a Debian 9.
Since the rendering crashes after a certain while, i render my movies in different slices. 
For the first slice of 3000 frames, everything goes well. For all the comming slices, the animation (titles and flags moving in and out of the video) get messed up and the animated object are shown at random times while rendering.
[image]
Does somebody has experienced something similar?
What am i missing ?

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: To be more specific, it seems, that when i want to render only a part of the movie, that the animations somehow get moved by the amount i reduce the timeline. Is there a setting witch binds the keyframes to the selected frames for render ?

Comment: On the second image, taken while rendering, one can see the marking in the timeline jumping to around frame 10000. It look like blender tries to find the object for the flag at this position to render into the actual frame. Note that during all this time, the markers for the keyframes for the map are visible in the timeline, so the flag should be there.

Comment: My hack is to render all out in images and stich it together with mencoder... but thats ugly. Somehow blender doesnt crash rendering the images, but rendering it as a h264 movie produces crashes at random places.